# How to pass a json object to a method which has a typed parameter in PHP 7.1.x

Tags: php, rest, fatal-error, php-7.1, stdclass

I'm having a PHP file, which will receive the POST data. Moreover I'm having a function which has a typed parameter. If I pass the POST data to that function it throws a FATAL ERROR.

I depicted the scenario in a simple code to reproduce the issue.

```php
<?php

class User
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$param = json_decode($data);

function printData(Phone $var)
{
    echo($var);
}

printData($param);
```

I executed the above script using POSTMAN, with the following body object

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"jhon"
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
[08-Jun-2019 01:43:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to printData() must be an instance of User, instance of stdClass given, called in /home/bala/server/test/test.php on line 17 and defined in /home/bala/server/test/test.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bala/server/test/test.php(17): printData(Object(stdClass))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/bala/server/test/test.php on line 12
```

How could I pass the object to this function with strict type? kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

```php
    function printData(Phone $var)
```

This line states that the `$var` parameter needs to be an instance of the `Phone` class. However, `json_decode()` doesn't know anything about particular classes and just decodes stuff into an instance of the generic `stdClass` class.

You need to either instantiate an instance of `Phone` using the values in `$param`, or you should modify the `$var` parameter in the `printData()` signature so that it does not require an instance of `Phone` to be passed in; eg, `function printData($var)`.